# MFC DoModal() Dialog is always on top across all applications

Tags: mfc

I have a dialog box (D1), which creates a new dialog box (D2) using DoModal().
What I've noticed is that, the dialog D2 is always on top. Even if I open a new application, the dialog D2 appears on top of it, while working with that application.

I want the dialog D2 to be on top always only in context of my application, and not across all the applications which I am using simultaneously. Could anyone tell me how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have the WS_EX_TOPMOST style set for your dialog?  It is unlikely to have anything to do with DoModal() or MFC.  It is likely a dialog style setting in your resource.  If you want help, you should provide the source for the dialog resource.

Comment: What you describe is standard behavior for modal dialogs: A modal dialog is always in front of it's owner window in the Z-order. If one of your modal dialogs is in front of all other windows, this is a bug.

Comment: @IInspectable but he said "even if I open a new application" indicating a different program.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: I was referring to the second paragraph in the question. What the OP desires is standard behavior for dialogs (or all owned windows, really).

Comment: @IInspectable I don't think he is saying that. He wants it on top in context of his application. It is. It is DoModal. But then he says "not across all applications which I am using simultaneously". So that application with it's popup window is always in the foreground obliterating the others. That is how I read it. Perhaps he can provide us with screenshots. Pictures say a thousand words.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: The OP is saying, that they want what is standard behavior (owned windows are in front of their respective owner in the Z-order). The OP is also saying, that their application exhibits different behavior, where a modal dialog is in front of all windows in the system. This is a bug, either in their code or MFC. Without seeing a [mcve], this question is asking us to guess.

Comment: Do you have the "System Modal" set to "True" on the Properties of the form in the Resource Editor?

Comment: What i want is that the modal dialog be on top always, but within the context of its application. What happens is that when i open another application, the modal dialog appears on top of the new application's window. Also, code sharing is not possible for some reasons. Also, I am quite new to MFC. @IInspectable

Comment: I will look into it and let you know @JoeWillcoxson

Comment: @AndrewTruckle you got it right

Comment: @sergiol Thanks a lot. It was set to true not for that window but for an underlying window. Setting it to false solved it !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks a lot. System Modal was set to true not for that window but for an underlying window. Setting it to false solved it !!